# setTexture applied to all createShape(GROUP) objects (Processing)

Tags: textures, processing

I'm trying to create a *piece* element (basically a group of shapes) and apply a texture (loaded image) at the top of it, in a rectangle (acting as box side):

```java
(...)

piece = createShape(GROUP);

PShape base = createShape(BOX, size, size, 20);
  base.setFill(#FFFFFF);
  base.translate(0, 0, 10);

PShape ...

PShape cover = createShape(RECT, -size/2, -size/2, size, size);
  cover.translate(0, 0, 20);
  cover.setTexture(texture);

piece.addChild(base);
piece.addChild ...
piece.addChild(cover);

shape(piece, pos.x, pos.y);
```

When rendering, texture is applied to all sides of all PShapes inside *piece* group. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Why would it be a bug?

Comment: I want to apply texture only to cover PShape, but it is applied also to base PShape and other PShapes inside piece.

I just noticed that applying a stroke (even if transparent) it behaves at it is supposed to do.

Comment: Does that mean you've fixed your problem?

Comment: Kind of. However, I still can't understand why is this happening. And I also found that if another PShape inside the group has not the same size, code breaks.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you post a [mcve] that demonstrates exactly what you're talking about.